# Switching column order using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two column layout which I would like to switch order on mobile devices. 
When I try `col-xs-push-12` it doesn't switch the columns, it merely places the first column out of sight.

Here is the code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        Content will go here
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: It appears its being `push`'d on viewports outside `xs` too.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Content above title on smaller devices? `xs` push,pull is supported in 3.1.

Comment: Use `col-sm-push-0` if you don't want it pushed on smaller devices

Comment: @Skelly That doesn't work > http://www.bootply.com/render/119734

Comment: @BeatAlex - there is no `col-sm-lg-0` class. @Imran - Is this what you're trying to do? http://www.bootply.com/119737

Comment: @Imran - Do you mean like this: http://www.bootply.com/119821

Comment: Ah yes this does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around would be to take a mobile-first approach and do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
    Content will go here
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```